# Do I require a transit visa? I'm am Indian citizen, travelling from Australia to India

Tags: indian-citizens, india, malaysia, kuala-lumpur

I'm Indian citizen, traveling to India from Australia with Malaysia Airlines for both flights. I have a 13.5-hour layover in Kuala Lumpur. Do I require a transit visa?

Answer (score 3):

As long as you stay airside, you don't need a transit visa – you'll stay in the same terminal, both flights being with MH. It's just going to be a long wait...

Note that in your case, whether you have one ticket or two doesn't matter, MH will tag your luggage all the way to India.

Comment: Indian citizens do not require a visa to enter Malaysia for up to 30 days.  Thus there is no need to stay in the terminal.

Comment: @Doc It was only for December. It is no longer valid. However, visa on arrival for a fee might be available.

Comment: And in either case it won't be a transit visa... :-)